# Drawing to an OpenGL texture in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have been working on modifying libstreaming so that I can stream a surfaceview up to Wowza instead of the camera.  I feel that I am now at the final stage and just missing one piece that I cannot seem to figure out.

Here is what I need to replace.  Everything works correctly when I use the camera and do the following,

```
cameraInstance.setPreviewTexture(glSurfaceView.getSurfaceTexture());
cameraInstance.startPreview();
```

glSurfaceView is a custom class that contains code to create a texture with glGenTextures method.

At this stage, I can start the app and images is transmitted to Wowza via libstreaming.  All happy.

Now, I want to replace the cameraInstance with my own code to draw directly to the texture.  How do I go about doing that?  How does the camera do it to draw directly to the texture?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw to an OpenGL texture using OpenGL?

Comment: Sorry I am only picking OpenGL for this portion of my project so I might be asking stupid questions.  But yes, I somehow need to draw into the texture using OpenGL.  From my research it seems to indicated that I need a framebufferobject?   Thanks.